# MySql Where Clause Parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("
    select * 
    from singlecustomer 
    where name like concat ('%',@search,'%') 
        or code like concat ('%',@search,'%') 
        or id like concat ('%',@search,'%')", con);

command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@search", "%"+sc.sc_SearchBox.Text+"%"));

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
sc.dgClientLog.DataSource = dt;
```

this is the method
that verify if the search is successful or not.

```
SearchClientDataGrid(sc);
if (sc.dgClientLog.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    sc.NoItemFoundLabel.Visible = true;
    sc.NoItemFoundLabel.BringToFront();
    return;
}
else
{
    sc.NoItemFoundLabel.Visible = false;
}
```

It works but whenever I search starting with the character "%" for Example: %David, it still work,
is there a way to remove %? I'm recently learning MySql Parameter to avoid Sql Injection. It just ticks me off that % actually work instead of returning no found.

Comment: `sc.sc_SearchBox.Text.Trim('%')`

Comment: hi fubo thanks for the reply. the % still works even with trim, I'd do a statement too, but I'm afraid it wont be a dynamic search since doing statement would make it application level search, not database level search.

Comment: could you specify your example a bit? I'm not sure if I'm getting this question right. Input / result / expected result

Comment: hi fubo,  I applied this to datagridview, by searching from database and feeding it up to dataset to display to datagridview. 
I get the error in input/result. 

example when i search name. David, it works fine, but when I add % character like this %David, it still output the result David, what I want to expect is if I type %David it shouldn't return a row from the table containing the data of David, because of the % character, if I try to search using #David, it doesn't return a row that's What I want to happen with % too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to escape the `%` character [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) with the mysql escape character `\`. Then it will not be treated as a special character anymore.

so the solution would be

```
string search = "%" + sc.sc_SearchBox.Text.Replace("%", @"\%") + "%";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@search",search));
```

probably you should take a look at the referenced table and also handle the other special character `_` which is also a wildcard character used by the `LIKE` search. The other escaping is handled by the mySQLParameter. e.g. the following turns `"` into `\"` (`MySqlHelper.EscapeString` is internally applied when you use parameters)

```
string result = MySqlHelper.EscapeString("foo\"bar");
```

Comment: It Worked!, I will read about MySqlHelper and EscapeString thanks for your Effort Fubo. thank you very muchhhh.